# How to prompt the default windows credentials dialog form for internet proxy in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, webproxy

My .NET app uses a WebService and, in some clients, I am getting HTTP 407 (proxy authentication required). So I need to ask the user to input his user/password credentials.

So, how to use the default Windows dialog? (see below)

Is it possible in .NET? Or will I need to build my own custom form?

[Internet Proxy Credentials Dialog http://grab.by/23II](http://grab.by/23II)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4693/using-the-credential-management-api/)

It contains a class that will get the Credential Dialog and an example of how to use it.